# Tips for golfing in Lean

Tags: code-golf, tips, lean

Lean is a theorem prover and programming language.  It's also as of writing the [Language of the Month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23916/56656)!

What tips do people have for golfing in Lean?  As always, tips should be specific to to Lean (e.g. "Remove comments" is not an answer), and stick to a single tip per answer.

Answer (score 5):

## Introductions

If you've just finished the natural number game you may be familiar with the `intro` tactic, this can be used to create implications / functions.  However this tactic is rarely the golfiest.

If your intro is the first part of your proof then an implicit forall is probably better.  Compare:

```lean
def q:list ℕ→ℕ:=by{intro x,induction x,exact 0,exact x_hd+x_ih}
```

with

```lean
def q(x:list ℕ):ℕ:=by{induction x,exact 0,exact x_hd+x_ih}
```

This is frequently always your best option.  However if the type of your function can be inferred you have other options.

```
def f:ℕ→ℕ:=by{intro x,exact x+3}
def f(x:ℕ):ℕ:=by{exact x+3}
def f:=λx,by{exact x+3}
def f(x):=by{exact x+3}
```

These are ordered by length so implicit forall (the last option is still implicit forall) is the shortest. But the lambda can expression can have the `def f:=` removed if the function is your submission, making it the shortest in that case.

Comment: Types on a `def` with parameters can be inferred too: `def f(x):=by{exact x+3}`, which is shorter in bytes because `λ` is two bytes.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Nice.  The lambda is still shorter if it's your main declaration.

Answer (score 4):

### Use `by` instead of `begin ... end`

`by` can be shorter than `begin` and `end`.

```
def foo(m:ℕ):m=m:=begin refl,end
```

is longer than

```
def bar(m:ℕ):m=m :=by refl
```

You can also use it for multiple tactics, though you'll need to encase the tactics in braces, as Wheat Wizard pointed out. For example, `by{rw add_assoc,refl}` is shorter than `begin rw add_assoc,refl end`.

Comment: You can use `by` even when there are multiple tactics, just enclose them in braces, e.g. `by{rw add_assoc,refl}`

Comment: if you use either `;` or `<|>` instead of `,` (I think `;` will usually be the most useful) you don't need braces either

Comment: @It'sNotALie. That's really cool, but I don't know how to add that, can you do it? (I made this answer CW so that people could edit it)

Answer (score 3):

### The `;` and `<|>` combinators.

`;` makes it so that all subgoals created by the last tactic have the next tactic applied; for example, `lemma asda (n : ℕ) : n = n := by { induction n; refl }` is a valid proof. As a bonus, it also allows you to not use the braces (e.g. `def k(n:ℕ):n=n:=by induction n;refl`).

The `<|>` is a bit more niche, but still useful; it allows you to do one tactic, and if it fails, the other instead. It also allows for no braces (although this is longer than `,`, so not as useful). For example:

```
example(x):0+x=x:=by induction x;refl<|>rw nat.zero_add
```